# Change view height on click

Tags: java, android, xml, onclick, height

I have a TextView, which is currently 0dp high and I want it to get 20dp higher with every click of a button

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

<Button
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: If it is 0dp high, how is it supposed to be clicked ?

Comment: The button (which is not 0dp high) is supposed to be clicked, the TextView (which is 0dp high) is not supposed to be clicked

Comment: You should modify your question then.

Comment: it says that the view is 0dp high and should get 20dp higher *with every click of a button*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change height of textview programmatically as-

```
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 20;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Now, you can get the previous height and add 20 to it every time button is clicked.

Comment: I don't know why LayoutParams worded to update the UI . . on the other hand is used to set direct layout hight wont work.
my code working fine with static data but when i use room db to get data from db it wont work to update the UI here is code in kotlin  V11.layoutParams.height = dpToPx(pointsValue[0])
But as soon as i used LayoutParam on one view all worked . I dont know the reson

Answer (score -1):

You can change the height or size of your through sharedpreferences in java simply declare the sharedpreference in the onClick method of your button in android as i have done below, your textView size will be changed on button Click:

MainActivity_java

```js
Button small = (Button) findViewById(R.id.small);
        small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teext);
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this.getBaseContext());
                tv.setTextSize(sharedPreferences.getFloat("FONT_SIZE", 30/*DEFAULT VALUE*/));

            }
            });
```

Main_XML

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Say Yes if the size of textView changes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/teext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The Size of text View will change on button click !"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="button"/>


</LinearLayout>
```